# Extending Button's Method -> "Preemptive" 5 second timeout

Tags: dynamic, button

This is an example from the documentation for `Button` :

```
DynamicModule[
    {a = "start"},
    {Button["does time out", Pause[6]; a = "end"],
     Dynamic[a]}
]
```

It shows that, with the default `Method -> "Preemptive"` option, the action times out after 5 seconds.

Is there a way to change this timeout for example to 10 seconds without setting the `Method` to `"Queued"`?

If this is not possible, is there a recommended way of detecting inside the GUI code running in the front end if there are currently Queued evaluations running?

Comment: See if [`DynamicEvaluationTimeout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicEvaluationTimeout.html) helps.

Comment: Michael, it works! Thank you. Why don't you write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DynamicEvaluationTimeout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicEvaluationTimeout.html) and `Style` may be used to locally set the dynamic timeout bound:

```
DynamicModule[{a = "start"},
 Style[{
   Button["does time out", Pause[6]; a = "end"],
   Dynamic[a]},
  DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 10]]
```